# How to save KeyValues from Dictionary to String

Tags: c#, string, dictionary, return-value

I have a problem with my Dictionary. I need to get the values out of there and save it to a string:

```
class CTestRack
{
    public String TestRackName { get; set; }
    public String NetworkName { get; set; }
    public String IPAddress { get; set; }
    public String MacAddress { get; set; }
    public string NewItemName;


    public void GetSessionName()
    {
        FileIniDataParser fileParser = new FileIniDataParser();
        IniData data = fileParser.ReadFile("config.ini");

        Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> newDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();

        Form1 _form1Object = new Form1();

        foreach (SectionData section in data.Sections)
        {
            var keyDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            foreach (KeyData key in section.Keys)
                keyDictionary.Add(key.KeyName.ToString(), key.Value.ToString());
            newDictionary.Add(section.SectionName.ToString(), keyDictionary);
        }

        if (_form1Object.comboBox2.SelectedIndex.ToString() != null)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

            foreach (var keyValue in newDictionary[NewItemName])
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", keyValue.Key, keyValue.Value);
            }
        }


    }
```

So basically the output would be:

> NewCCReduced4
>   Key: name, Value: NewCCReduced4.cone.bombardier.com
>   Key: ipaddress, Value: 10.167.21.11
>   Key: macaddress, Value: 000bab46edeb

Now as you can guess I want that the output: Name NewCCReduced4.cone.bombardier.com would be saved in the String TestRackName.

Maybe someone has a hint how I should continue?

Comment: Why iteratively add things to a dictionary then iteratively write the dictionary out to a string, your loops that create the dictionaries, could just create a string that contains the values you want.

Comment: I recommend a string.Join string.Format combination for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there, just drop the `[NewItemName]`:

```
foreach (var keyValue in newDictionary)
```

Comment: The problem is that the string would only be like temporary, so if the user selects some other element than he has the new information in the "Temp-String"

Answer (score 1):

```
var txt =string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
    newDictionary
        .Select (d => string.Format("{0}:{1}", d.Key, 
                    string.Join(", ", d.Value.Select (d2 => string.Format("{0}:{1}", d2.Key, d2.Value))))));
```

No loops, just Console.Write(txt)

**EDIT** - didn't realize it was a Dictionary of Dictionaries